# Error when converting eval() to JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, parsing, eval

I have a snippet code with eval() as shown below:

```js
var data = "{listUpdated:[],listConflictOrMerge:[]}"; //returned from Ajax

var results = eval("(" + data + ")");

console.log(results)
```

As you can see, the **data** is my input value returned from ajax request. When using eval(), it can be parsed to 2 array objects.

And now I don't want to use eval() anymore, so I try using JSON.parse(). However, there is an error.

```js
var data = "{listUpdated:[],listConflictOrMerge:[]}"; //returned from Ajax

var results = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(results)
```

my purpose is that I don't want to use eval() to parse data anymore.

- So, is there any ways can do that?.
- I try using JSON, but I got unlucky. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: You can't use `JSON.parse` to execute arbitrary JavaScript code. It's only meant for JSON.

Comment: `"{listUpdated:[],listConflictOrMerge:[]}"` this is not valid JSON - the keys need to be in double quotes. This is the correct representation: `'{"listUpdated":[],"listConflictOrMerge":[]}'`

Comment: you're right, @vlaz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
   

var data = '{"listUpdated":[],"listConflictOrMerge":[]}';

var results =JSON.parse(data);

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 7):

The data you're trying to parse isn't valid JSON, so `JSON.parse` can't parse it.

Keys in JSON objects must be quoted, just like any other string. The form you're using is valid in Javascript, but invalid in JSON.